# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, maven, jdbc

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver'
```

I'm getting this warning while starting my application, can you help me how to solve it? It's WARN, no error or exception.
(it is in my maven,spring,hibernate application), i have exceptions when i want to access my database via hibernate, but i'm not sure if this is causing the problem, thanks.

Comment: Looks like the postgresql.jar is missing in your classspath.

Comment: @Jens .jar file into classpath? can you explain what exactly should i do? what jar file?

Comment: [Here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)you can download the jar contains the postgressql Driver. How do you start your application?

Comment: This jar: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: it's webapp, i just run it via IDE

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood "add .jar into classpath", but i already have it i think: http://screenshot.cz/6YJM4/ (it's external library of my project)

Comment: and i tried to put the jar into WEB-INF/lib folder but the WARN keeps...

Comment: If you're using Maven, ignore the people talking about manipulating the jar directly and declare it as a dependency.

Comment: yes, I'm using maven, i have the dependency, but i don't know why there is the warning.

Comment: Since I cannot add an answer to your question because it was already answered elsewhere ( still not very satisfying to me ), I will add an comment: Since you are using idea and maven please check this path `project structure -> artifacts -> <yourAppName:war exploded> -> output layout tab -> WEB-INF -> lib` and check if you have there in the lib folder all the dependencies from pom.xml. I don't know why this folder wasn't being  updated by Maven. Here is the location where all your jars should be ( as stated in the accepted answer). Maybe I've, like you have, missed a configuration or something

Answer (score 2):

Add the dependency on the postgresql driver to your `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i already have this dependency

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: im using intelij idea