# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am facing this problem since 3-4 days and really don't know what to do....

Employee.java

```
        package com.tutorialspoint.test;


        public class Employee {

            EmployeeManager employeeManager;

        private String fname;
        private String lname;
        private int dob;
        private String add;
        private int id;



        public void setfname(String fname){
            this.fname=fname;
        }
        public String getfname(){
            return fname;
        }
        public void setlname(String lname){
            this.lname=lname;
        }
        public String getlname(){
            return lname;
        }
        public void setdob(int dob){
            this.dob=dob;
        }
        public int getdob(){
            return dob;
        }
        public void setadd(String add){
            this.add=add;
        }

            public String getadd() {
                return add;
            }
        public void setid(int id){
            this.id=id;
        }
        public int getid(){
            return id;
        }
        public void setEmployeeManager(EmployeeManager employeeManager) {
            this.employeeManager = employeeManager;
        }

        }
```

EmployeeDAO.java

```
    package com.tutorialspoint.test;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

    import java.io.Serializable;


    public class EmployeeDAO implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Employee employee;
    private DataSource dataSource;
        //SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
            this.dataSource=dataSource;
            this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
        }

        public int saveEmployee(Employee employee) {

            String fname = employee.getfname();
            String lname = employee.getlname();
            int dob = employee.getdob();
            String add = employee.getadd();
            int id = employee.getid();
            Object p[] = { fname, lname, dob, add, id };
            String query = "insert into employee values(?,?,?)";
            return this.jdbcTemplate.update(query, p);
        }

        /*
         * public int deleteEmployee(int id){ String sql
         * ="delete from employee where id = ?"; return
         * this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]{new Integer(id)}); }
         */

        public int delete() {
            return this.jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = ?",
                    new Object[] { employee.getid() });
        }

        public void setEmployee(Employee employee){
            this.employee=employee;
        }
        public Employee getEmployee() {
            return employee;
        }

         public List<Employee> getAllEmployee(Employee employee){
                return this.jdbcTemplate.query("select * from employee",new RowMapper<Employee>(){  

                  public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws  SQLException {  
                        Employee employee=new Employee();  

                        employee.setfname(rs.getString(1));  
                        employee.setlname(rs.getString(2));  
                        employee.setdob(rs.getInt(3));
                        employee.setadd(rs.getString(4));
                        employee.setid(rs.getInt(5));

                        return employee;  
                      }  
                  });  
                  }

    }






> applicationContext.xml

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

        <!-- Scan the com.itcuties.registration package for Spring -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint.test" />

        <bean id="employee" class="com.tutorialspoint.test.Employee" >
       </bean>

       <bean id="em" class="com.tutorialspoint.test.EmployeeManager">
     <property name="employee" ref="employee"></property>
     <property name="edao" ref="edao"></property>
     </bean>

      <bean id="ds" 
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
          <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
          <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"/>
          <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
          <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
       </bean>



     <bean id="edao" class="com.tutorialspoint.test.EmployeeDAO">
     <property name="employee" ref="employee"></property>
      <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
     </bean>

    </beans>
```

> stack
>             org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'

```
        javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
            at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
            at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
            at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
            at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
            at com.tutorialspoint.test.EmployeeDAO.delete(EmployeeDAO.java:53)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:130)
            at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
            at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
            ... 20 more
        Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
            ... 33 more
        Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.postgresql.Driver)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2822)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1415)
            ... 37 more
```

Is this definition for jdbc connection in applicationContext.xml efficient or need some code....

Comment: Are you sure your postgre driver jar is in the classpath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460934/cannot-load-jdbc-driver-class-com-postgresql-jdbc-driver) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904756/class-not-found-loading-jdbc-org-postgresql-driver

Comment: D:\WorkspaceNew\J1spring\target\J1spring-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib.Is this path correct?

Answer (score 1):

Pratik, If you have a look at exception trace properly the root exception is UnsupportedClassVersionError.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.postgresql.Driver)
```

Which means that postgres jar which you have included in your project is not compatible with JDK/JVM version of your runtime. Make sure that you include jars which are compatible to your JDK/JVM environment version.